# When EditText has a hint, look it double the View

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-edittext, hint

For sure, i'am forgetting something to easy, but i've already try much things.

I have an EditText, thats when i set a hint, looks the android double it. The hint only dissapear when i set value on "both" fields.
All around of task to remove hint when edittext is focused.

[two fields EditText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpVOv.png)

[With content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDmoi.png)

MyFragment

```
class FormFragment : Fragment(), View.OnFocusChangeListener {

private var _binding: FormFragmentBinding? = null
private val bindingForm get() = _binding!!
private val model: GeneratorViewModel by activityViewModels()

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = FormFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return bindingForm.root
}

private var upper: Boolean = false
private var lower: Boolean = false
private var numbers: Boolean = false
private var symbols: Boolean = false

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    fun onSelectBox(button: CompoundButton?) {
        if ( button != null ) {
            when (button.id) {
                bindingForm.checkboxUppercase.id -> {
                    upper = true
                }
                bindingForm.checkboxLowercase.id -> {
                    lower = true
                }
                bindingForm.checkboxNumbers.id -> {
                    numbers = true
                }
                bindingForm.checkboxSymbols.id -> {
                    symbols = true
                }
            }
        }
    }

    bindingForm.checkboxUppercase.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, _ -> onSelectBox(compoundButton) }
    bindingForm.checkboxLowercase.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, _ -> onSelectBox(compoundButton) }
    bindingForm.checkboxNumbers.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, _ -> onSelectBox(compoundButton) }
    bindingForm.checkboxSymbols.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, _ -> onSelectBox(compoundButton) }

    bindingForm.generateBtn.setOnClickListener {
        val length = bindingForm.lenghtField.text.toString()
        model.generate(length.toInt(), upper, lower, numbers, symbols)
    }

    bindingForm.display.doOnTextChanged { _, _, _, _ ->
        bindingForm.display.letterSpacing = Float.fromBits(0)
    }

    bindingForm.cleanBtn.setOnClickListener { cleanAll() }

    model.passwordGenerated.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        bindingForm.display.text = it
    })
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}

override fun onFocusChange(view: View?, hasFocus: Boolean) {
    if(hasFocus){
        view?.let {
            if(!it.id.equals(bindingForm.lenghtField) && bindingForm.lenghtField.isInEditMode){
                bindingForm.lenghtField.clearFocus()
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun cleanAll() {
    bindingForm.checkboxLowercase.isChecked = false
    bindingForm.checkboxUppercase.isChecked = false
    bindingForm.checkboxNumbers.isChecked = false
    bindingForm.checkboxSymbols.isChecked = false
    bindingForm.lenghtField.text?.clear()
    bindingForm.display.text = ""
}
```

}

XML

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/formFragment"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_marginTop="100sp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/formFragment"
    android:id="@+id/llTitle"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/formTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title_form"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/lenghtField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/password_length"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/formFragment"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/formFragment"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/llTitle"
    android:id="@+id/llOptions"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_uppercase"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/chivo"
        android:text="@string/checkbox_uppercase"/>

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox_lowercase"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/checkbox_lowercase"
        android:fontFamily="@font/chivo"/>

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox_numbers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/checkbox_numbers"
        android:fontFamily="@font/chivo"/>

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox_symbols"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/checkbox_symbols"
        android:fontFamily="@font/chivo"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_form"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:id="@+id/generate_btn"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/llDisplay"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/llOptions"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/llOptions"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/llOptions"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/displayLabel"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/advent_pro"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/password_generated" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/display"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/password_field"/>
</LinearLayout>


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/formFragment"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/formFragment"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/llDisplay"
    android:text="@string/clean"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:id="@+id/clean_btn"/>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints look a little wacky.

I would redo them, you have the `llOptions` constrained on all 4 sides to the  `formFragment` which is

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

BUT

you also have `lenghtField` constrained to the top of `llOptions`, and `formTitle` to the top of `lenghtField`.

AND

the unnamed `LinearLayout` at the bottom is constrained to the bottom of `llOptions`.

Although this may look right on display because `llOptions` is a fixed-ish size, but logically speaking it doesn't and is most likely your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your awnser. Use match_parent in `llOptions` does not work fine for me, but i've remove de fixed width.
I will update the code, but maybe the better is redo it. I put a button to clean all, then i see, that seems it caches de texts in views